# ASP.net Common menu and navbar across website

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

We would like to create a new website with a common menu and navbar across all the pages (except start/login page) .
The thing is that we are going to use the twitter bootstrap framework and dont know if this could be achieved with the framework only (or with any html + css trick)...

Previously we have used iframes for this cases but we prefer to do a frameless website this time and dont know how the framework will behave with master pages...

Any suggestions? If the only way is using master pages, could you provide some sample or link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use asp.net master pages. I think this has nothing to do with twitter bootstrap framework.

Create a empty parent masterpage with a header and a body container only.
Create two web forms using the parent master page for the start and login pages.
Create a children master page using the parent master page and implement the menu on the children.
Create everything else using the children master page so you will have a menu on every page.

If you want a menu less page, use the parent.masterpage. If you want the menu version, use the children.masterpage.

Comment: We will grant the response to you as you included the useful tip about parent.masterpage & children.masterpage, but we upvoted all responses so thanks to everyone!

Comment: Thank you. It's nice to a have a empty parent master page because I'm very sure you use something like a global jquery library. You can add your global libraries in the parent masterpage. Without the parent master page you will need to add the library to the login, start and children masterpage. Looks easy with 3 pages, but when your project gets bigger you can find yourself in a big mess.

Answer (score 2):

[Master page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is the way to go. Here is a [walk through](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ehszf8ax%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You should use a master page. Here is a link to the asp.net tutorial on master pages: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages